# Force SimpleXML to NOT replace special chars

Tags: php, simplexml, htmlspecialchars

I'm using SimpleXML to create XML document.
How can I force it to **NOT** replace special chars by their & alternatives?

this code

```
<root>
    <test>
        &lt;west&gt;&amp;&quot;+ěščřžýáíé=&lt;/west&gt;
    </test>
</root>
```

should be

```
<root>
    <test>
        <west>&"+ěščřžýáíé=</west>
    </test>
</root>
```

Comment: `<west>` is a new tag. Either you add new tag or have html-entities.

Comment: show code in how you are creating the xml document.

Comment: `$xml->addChild("<west>&"+ěščřžýáíé=</west>");` I want to add it as pure text, so it will not be saved as new XML tag nor escaped.
I'm creating resulting document like this:
`$dom = dom_import_simplexml($xml);`
`$dom->ownerDocument->formatOutput = true;`
`$result = $dom->ownerDocument->saveXML();`

Comment: Please click [edit] under your question, and add a [mcve] of your current code, with sample input and desired output. Don't add the code in comments, as they don't format very well, and are easily overlooked by future readers.